# Where to find the packages inside Lucene.Net.Analysis?

Tags: c#, lucene.net, analyzer

Wish u a nice week! Mine didn’t started that well, since I can't find something seemingly straightforward, the namespaces inside Lucene.Net.Analysis. I have installed, using NuGet, the Lucene.Net 3.0.3 lib and added the reference to my project, but I can't access the namespaces and classes inside Analysis. It seems like I am missing something trivial.

The namespaces I am looking for: http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/dd/de5/namespace_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you additionally need the **Lucene.Net Contrib 3.0.3** lib: https://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/